# Pindrop or crosshair after address search in CartoDB?

Tags: carto

The basic search box feature supplied by CartoDB centers the map on the result ... but for a user this may not be intuitive and furthermore, on maps with lots of data (like parcels) it might be unclear exactly where the "center" is. Is there a way to provide some sort of crosshairs, "flash" or pindrop after an address search?  For my project it is crucial that a viewer can search for an address, then navigate to data provided by the visualization connected to that address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature scheduled in the CartoDB roadmap, it'll be available soon :-) You can see the issue at: https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/4914

EDIT: The feature is already in production!